# What does "SparseArray - there can be gaps in the indices" mean?

Tags: java, android, data-structures, containers, sparse-array

Developing a program which uses hash map with integer as keys and objects as values. I keep on getting Lint warning informing SparseArray is more efficient and when I read about the same it was given in this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) that, there can be gaps in the indices. What does that actually mean, I am not able to get.

Does it mean, if I have keys like 1,5, 10 then array size will be 3 with indices 1, 5, 10. (Or) array size will be 11 with objects present for 1, 5, 10 indices and rest are empty?

Please clarify me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense more if you look at the [source code for SparseArray](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/SparseArray.java). All it has is two arrays - one containing the keys and the other containing the values; so your first reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 4):

The increased efficiency of `SparseArray` is not only due to the different structure (as the other answers pointed out), but also due to the fact that you are avoiding [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) when using `int` as a key.

In other words, when using e.g. `map.get(1)`, you are actually performing the equivalent of `map.get(Integer.valueOf(1))`. That is, you're converting an `int` primitive to an `Integer` class instance.

With `SparseArray`, there's no type conversion of this kind, you're just using an `int`. Check out the autoboxing link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the keys 1, 5 & 10 from your example, effectively resulting in a  `SparseArray` with the length of 3.